# Creation of database in Eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, jdbc

```
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");
                System.out.println("Connection Established");
                
                System.out.println("Creating Database");
                stmt=con.createStatement();
                String sql="CREATE DATABASE ALAN";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                System.out.println("Database Created Successfully");
```

I am getting this error every time whether Database presents or not:

> **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed    ORA-01100: database already mounted**

Comment: Not a direct answer, but may we ask why you are trying to _create_ a database from Java code?  I would say this is a fairly unusual requirement.  Consider doing the DDL plumbing directly on your Oracle database, then just handle the querying from Java.

Comment: > "CREATE DATABASE ALAN"

Does this DDL statement work from your SQL command prompt? What is the message that you get?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a "database" is a physical instance, including processes, initialization parameter files, redo log files, and data files. It is not the same meaning as "database" in MySQL, SQL Server, or most other databases, where a "database" is synonymous with "schema". In Oracle, "user" and "schema" are synonymous. You are seeing this error because the "xe" *database* already exists, is mounted and running, and you have connected to it. You cannot issue a "create database" command from a connection to a running database.

See here for examples of "create database" usage in Oracle:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/create.htm#ADMIN11073
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5004.htm#SQLRF01204

I suspect you are actually looking for the "create user" command, to create a schema within the database to contain objects like tables, indexes, and views, etc.

- https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-users-grant-them-privileges-and-remove-them-in-oracle-database
- https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-create-user/
- https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/users/create_user.php